# MySQL Database is found empty on my Linux server - How to know the reason?

Tags: mysql

I have a VM from Contabo Hosting and I have configured CWP Pro (CentOS Web Panel) as an alternative to Cpanel. I have few sites on this server, not very high traffic sites.

Yesterday I noticed that one of wordpress site's database is empty. It had data from past 2 years. The database appears to be reset, because admin user account is gone, woocommerce tables are gone, no blog post exists.

Now I want to know where to look in Server logs, to begin and investigation about what happened ? Secondly, is there a way to restore this data, I had backup setting checked in CWP for this site, but I do not  know if mySQL was getting backed-up or not.

I am Running - MySQL version: 10.1.44-MariaDB
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: This sounds absolutely terrible :(  Did you try to contact your hosting service provider?

Comment: it is not a managed service, so i am responsible